# Python Pandas Referencing ambiguous column and rows in a function

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

I have two dataframes

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Foo': ['A','B','C','D','E'],
'Score': [4,6,2,7,8]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Bar': ['Z','Y','X','W','V'],
'Score': [5,10,10,5,9]
})

print (df)
print (df2)
```

and  a function:

```
def DiffMatrix(df, df2):
    n=pd.DataFrame()
    for i in range(len(df2)):
        x = df2.ix[df.index[i], 'Score']
        y= x - df['Score']
        n = n.append(y, ignore_index=True)
    return n

diff= DiffMatrix(df, df2)
print (diff)

[5 rows x 2 columns]
   0  1  2  3  4
0  1 -1  3 -2 -3
1  6  4  8  3  2
2  6  4  8  3  2
3  1 -1  3 -2 -3
4  5  3  7  2  1

[5 rows x 5 columns]
```

But If I change the index or change the columns names like:

```
df=df.set_index('Foo')
df2=df2.set_index('Bar')
```

or

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Bar': ['Z','Y','X','W','V'],
'ScoreX': [5,10,10,5,9]
})
```

the function would not work because the reference relies on the column name 'Score'. Is there a way to change the code to reference `df['Score']` ambiguously as the first column and also accommodate the changes in the index so the output would become if I change the indexes:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
Z   1   -6  3   -2  -3
Y   6   4   8   3   2
X   6   4   8   3   2
W   1   -1  3   -2  -3
V   5   3   7   2   1
```

Comment: Thats a weird request. Do you need a function that can accept DataFrames and still work the same if  an arbitrary column is set as index? . Also have in mind that the first column won't always be the same if you create the df from a dict.

Comment: @elyase Yes I am trying to make just a function that has arbitrary column names and row names and have it work the same. If the column is not always the same i might have to add a try loop to count the number of columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference Panda's columns by their index so if you know that you are always going to want to reference the 2nd column (0th based indexing) then you can do something like this.

Instead of:

```
y= x - df['Score']
```

Do this:

```
y= x - df[df.columns[1]]
```

## Edit

As per the request of the OP concerning choosing specific rows you can use `pandas.DataFrame.iloc[...]`

For example you could do:

```
diff.iloc[[0]]
```

on your `diff` data frame which produces an output of:

```
   0  1  2  3  4
0  1 -1  3 -2 -3
```

And in case you ever wanted to select multiple rows that you could use slicing or a list of row indices you want

```
#slicing
diff.iloc[1:4]
```

gives you

```
   0  1  2  3  4
1  6  4  8  3  2
2  6  4  8  3  2
3  1 -1  3 -2 -3
```

and

```
#list of row indices
diff.iloc[[0,2,4]]
```

yields

```
   0  1  2  3  4
0  1 -1  3 -2 -3
2  6  4  8  3  2
4  5  3  7  2  1
```

Comment: Is there any way of referencing rows the same way?

Comment: The row one does not really work well if I changed: `df=df.set_index('Foo')`,`df2=df2.set_index('Bar')` The part `x = df2.ix[df.index[i], 'Score']` would not work if I changed it to `df.iloc` instead of `df.index`. Even if I changed df2.xi to `df2.iloc` it would not work any suggestions?

Comment: @ccsv It's not working because the indices for `df` and `df2` are different when you set them to be `Foo` and `Bar`. If you do `df.ix[df.index[i], 'Score']` then you won't have any errors. Notice however that they are both referencing `df`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `.iloc` method to access your data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2], 'B':[3,4]}, index=['x', 'y'])
df

   A  B
x  1  3
y  2  4
```

So to access 2nd row:

```
df.iloc[1,:]

A    2
B    4
Name: y, dtype: int64
```

And to access 2nd column

```
df.iloc[:,1]

x    3
y    4
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

Indeed you can mix them and get a scalar:

```
df.iloc[1,1]

4
```